# OpenCV in Mac OS X with Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, opencv

I want to work with OpenCV in Mac OS X with Eclipse IDE. I followed the instructions in this link  [Installing opencv for java on MAC OS X and Configuring Eclipse](http://sumitkumariit.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-install-opencv-for-java-on-mac.html) and builded OpenCV correctly.But after the build process (no error) I can't found any .jar files in my build/bin folder. What is the reason for this?

Comment: I have the same problem; even I tried different versions of openCv recently released by following instructions step by step.

The build is finished with no error. But there is no *.jar files.

Comment: please check the cmake output, before compiling

Answer (score 0):

You need to have apache ant in your path. In order to add ant in your classpath, download the binary release from apache ant site and after unzipping it in any folder

```
export PATH=$PATH:<Extracted Folder path>/bin/
```

This is apparent from the cmake log. Without ant in path, you will see ,

```
--   Java:
--     ant:                         **NO**
--     JNI:                         /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers
--     Java tests:                  NO
--
```

With ant in classpath, you will see

```
--   Java:
--     ant:                         **/Users/asing20/ant/bin/ant (ver 1.9.4)**
--     JNI:                         /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers
--     Java tests:                  YES
```

OpenCV uses ant for building the java jar files. Of course all your paths will vary.

Also, note that the jar files are in bin folder.

```
L-IDC10LDKQ2-M:build asing20$ pwd
/Users/asing20/opencv/opencv-2.4.9/build 
L-IDC10LDKQ2-M:build asing20$ find . | grep jar
./bin/opencv-249.jar
./bin/opencv-249.jar.dephelper
./modules/java/test/.build/bin/opencv-249.jar
./modules/java/test/.build/build/jar
./modules/java/test/.build/build/jar/opencv-test.jar
./modules/java/test/.build/lib/junit-4.11.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding the JAVA_HOME environment variable per the instructions on this page:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html

> If CMake can’t find Java in your system set the JAVA_HOME environment
>   variable with the path to installed JDK before running it. E.g.:
>
> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle